# Select MySQL with 2 tables conditions, Is this right?

Tags: mysql, select, where

Tables:

```
agencia (nome_agencia, cidade_agencia, fundos)

cliente (nome_cliente, rua_cliente, cidade_cliente)

conta (nome_agencia, numero_conta, saldo)

emprestimo (nome_agencia, numero_emprestimo, total)

depositante (nome_cliente, numero_conta)

devedor (nome_cliente, numero_emprestimo)
```

I want to show results from "nome_cliente" that has "saldo" between 200 and 1000.  Will this query work?

```
SELECT nome_cliente, saldo 
FROM cliente, conta 
WHERE nome_cliente AND numero_conta >200,numero_conta<1000);
```

Comment: How are `cliente` and `conta` related?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cliente` is connected to `conta` via `depositante`, then it sounds like you want:

```
SELECT nome_cliente, saldo 
FROM cliente
    INNER JOIN depositante ON client.nome_cliente = depositante.nome_cliente
    INNER JOIN conta ON depositante.numero_conta = conta.numero_conta
WHERE conta.saldo >= 200
    AND conta.saldo <= 1000;
```